# Using a select in the set of an update pgsql

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, subquery

Hello i'm wondering why I can't use an SELECT in my SET of an UPDATE like this :

```
UPDATE "WU_Users" SET (SELECT "colonnesName" FROM colonnes WHERE "id" = i) = '0/0' WHERE "IDWU_Users" = (SELECT "idUser" FROM query WHERE "id" = i);
```

I get this error :

```
erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « SELECT »
LIGNE 22 :             UPDATE "WU_Users" SET (SELECT "colonnesName" FRO...
```

Comment: I have no idea what it is you are trying to do. I would suggest taking a look at the Examples section here [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) to see what is possible.

Comment: I"m trygin to use a SELECT in the SET statement.

Comment: You can't.  Look at the examples for what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are attempting to derive the column name to be updated from a column in another table. However, parsing an SQL statement requires the structural components (table names, column name, view names, ...) to be fixed before the statement can be parsed. What you are attempting would require parsing part of the statement inside parsing the statement. Currently, that is not going to happen. To accomplish what you are attempting will require dynamic SQL in order to generate the UPDATE statement at run time. Something like:

```
create or replace 
procedure update_wu_users_from_idwu_users(i integer)  -- assumes i as parameter as it is not defined
  language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
  k_update_stmt constant text = 
     $stmt$ update wu_users set %I = '0/0'
             where wu_users = 
                   (select iduser 
                      from query        -- assumes query is a table, view, or materalized view
                     where id = i
                   )
     $stmt$;
  
     l_update_column text; 
     l_update_stmt   text;
    
begin 
     select colonnesname
       into l_update_column 
       from columns
      where id = i; 
     
     if not found then
        raise exception 'No column name found on table colonnes for id=%',i;
     end if; 
   
     l_update_stmt = format(k_update_stmt,k_update_stmt);
     raise notice '%', l_update_stmt;         -- for debigging for prod raise_log might be better
     execute l_update_stmt;      
end;
$$;
```

**NOTE:** In the absence of table definition and test data the above IS NOT tested. Nor will I quarantine it complies. It is offered as example.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I want. I'm not asking about that. Just asking to replace the "SET" statement by a SELECT one. I already know how to do that if I specify the column name. Here i'm trying to retrieve the column name from a TEMP table

Comment: I understand perfectly well. What you want, getting the column name from a temp table then using the retrieved column in an Update statement, is exactly what that function does. You simply cannot use **set = (select column_name...)** in either SQL nor PLPGSQL when that column name is NOT prior to run time.  The only additional "stuff" is how I define long strings (hate them in the execution section) and a minimum data validation